# Is it bad practice to overload an existing function with templates?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a function `int foo()`, then I realise it would be nice to have two different modes, say, fast and default, s o i design the below templates.

```
template<typename T>
int foo() { doDefaultStuff; }

template<> int foo<FastMode> { doFastStuff; }
```

then I try to invoke my templates like

```
if (enable_fast_mode)
    a = foo<FastMode>();
else
    a = foo<>();
```

But the `else` part will not compile as `no matching function for call to 'foo()'`

Is it bad practice to declare both `int foo()` and `template<> int foo()`, 
or should I invoke default mode with `int foo<void>()` ?

Comment: It's not bad practice *per se*, there are however better ways of achieving it.

Comment: Why not just have `foo()` and `fastfoo()`? What do the templates gain you?

Comment: That isn't an overload; it's a specialization. And the `else` fails because the template argument isn't optional and you're not providing one, so your "fast and default" is a misnomer, because there is not such "default".  I concur with Colin, templates for this seem pointless unless you're planning on utilizing deduction in one of your parameters, which you're currently not.

Comment: if you are doing this on a lot of functions, maybe just put them in namespaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your specific problem you can do something like this:

```
enum class Mode
{
   Slow,
   Fast,
   Default
};

template<Mode T = Mode::Default>
int foo() { ...; }

template<> 
int foo<Mode::Fast>() { ...; }
```

This makes a call like `foo<>()` possible because it defaults to `Mode::Default`.

Comment: Have an upvote for begin 10s faster than me :) Also, you don't have to specify `<>` when calling `foo`, just use `foo()`.

Answer (score 0):

To try to answer to the general function, according to Herb Sutter it is not recommended to specialize function templates, here is the [article](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm). You can run into unexpected situations when mixing overloading and specialization, see the Dimov/Abrahams example in the article.